# Tag commit in VSCode

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I am trying to Create a ***Tag*** Commit in Git via VSCode. VS code's built in Git has a commit option. But How to create a  *Tag Commit* via VS Code

Comment: It has indeed been added as a menu option in v1.51.  See https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_51#_git-tag-commands-in-submenu

Answer (score 50):

You can open the Command Palette (`Ctrl + Shift + P`) and choose `Git: Create Tag`.

Give the tag a name and press `Enter`.

To push the tag to the remote server, you can open the Command Palette again and choose `Git: Push (Follow Tags)`.

(It seems this is the PR that included the feature: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/pull/26999)

Answer (score 11):

In addition of `Git: Create Tag`, you now have `Git: Push Tag` with VSCode 1.52 (Nov. 2020) and [PR 110096](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/110096), which fixes [issue 109799](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/109799).

- `Git: Create Tag` is [`git tag -m '...' aTag`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag) to create locally an annotated tag,
- `Git: Push Tag` is [`git push --tags`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt---tags), to publish local tags to the remote repository.

Even more automatic: the [new setting `git.followTagsWhenSync`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/1964af9dfc83c3c488f9b9d3cf227bd770f632ae/release-notes/v1_52.md#git-new-settings): Follow tags when running Git: Sync.

Comment: Certainly, in v1.57.1 the `git.pushTags` option seems to have been removed.

Comment: @woter324 Thank you for the feedback. It was not removed, but *renamed* (as mentioned in  https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/103281#issuecomment-743300318): `git.followTagsWhenSync`. I have updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Can you break it down in a simply explanation on what Git push tag actually does when you run it?  So that folks know the difference between that and Git: create tag?

Comment: @klewis Sure, I have edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 8):

Open the command line in the git repo and type "git tag mytag".

There is currently no way to add a tag inside of the VS Code test editor.

Comment: But my Git Repo is in a Network folder. CMD cannot open in network location Produces following Error `CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.`

Comment: You need to clone your repository locally, tag it, and push to git. All operations on Git occur locally and you should never store your active working repo on a network share. Everyone should have a local copy on their machene.

Comment: Is there a way to tag a specific commit? I know you can do it from git command line, but is there a way within VSCode?